# Use .htaccess To Redirect Page Without Changing URL With 'mod_rewrite'

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a script on my page that checks the url for the word signing. If the word exists, it shows the signin form in a dropdown on page load. I'd like to avoid creating extra files on the server, so I was wondering how I could do this:

When the user is at either of these urls:

http://abramobile.com/signin
http://abramobile.com/sign-in

Then direct the page back to the homepage, but leave 'signin' or 'sign-in' in the URL so that the script on my page detects that it's in the URL.

What would the mod_rewrite be to put in my .htaccess file? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. This matches against the URI being exactly `/signin` or `/sign-in` and internally rewrite the URI to `/` so that that gets served.

```
RewriteRule ^sign-?in$ / [L]
```